# 640 x 480 image formation from OV5647 raspberry pi camera v1

Tags: opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi, camera

I want to figure out exactly what is happening when I create a 640x480 pixel image from the OV5647 Pi camera v1.

This is what I think so far:

We start with the full FoV 2592x1944 pixel resolution with aspect ratio 4:3.

Now 640x480 resolution image is also 4:3 aspect and based on full FoV.

We start by binning:
| Width | Height |
|----|----|
|2592|1944|
|1296|972|
|648|486|

e.g. 2592/2 = 1296; 1296/2 = 648

1944/2 = 972; 972/2=486

So after binning we get resolution of 648 x 486 but we want the output to be 640 x 480 so we have to deal with the extra 8 pixels horizontally and the extra 6 vertical pixels on the binned image.

My question is what actually happens to create an output image frame for the following cases:
640 x 480 resolution video is recorded with raspivid e.g. console command:

```
raspivid -o myvid.h264 -w 640 -h 480 -t 60000
```

If possible could someone explain the slight variation I see with 640 x 480 images create with raspivid and with OpenCV 4.0.0. The content of the images seems somewhat different e.g. slightly displaced but I am not sure if this is simple displacement e.g. taking from slightly different FoV or is one of the outputs actually performing a scale operation on the 648x486 binned image to generate the 640x480 result e.g. I have assumed that only binning and FoV clipping is done but actual scaling is possibility too especially for opencv.
Code for camera image is captured with OpenCV 4.0.0:

```
cv::VideoCapture* video_capture_cap_;
video_capture_cap_ = new cv::VideoCapture();
    video_capture_cap_->open(0);
    if (video_capture_cap_->isOpened()) {
      video_capture_cap_->set(
          cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,
          640);
      video_capture_cap_->set(
          cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,
          480);
      video_capture_cap_->set(
          cv::CAP_PROP_FPS,
          49);
```

Comment: *do not* use pointers for this purpose. this is enough: `cv::VideoCapture cap();` to replace the first two lines (and change the `->` to `.`, and the variable name)

Comment: Yes, you are right but code copied and pasted from codebase where video_capture_cap_ is class member rather than local variable...hence the use of pointer but I did change when pasting into message showing local instantiation...

Comment: I do think the raspberry pi forum has more knowledgeable people. even this link doesn't mention exactly when and how much is cropped, but you can assume that binning works on integer numbers of bins (usually /2, /4, *maybe* /3), and no resampling is done, and in fact the "excess" is just cropped: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fov.html

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: es, the excess does seem to be cropped but I was wondering whether the opencv image construction is the same....there is slight but noticeable difference...that is not resolved by overlaying the two images e,g, one taken from raspivid and one taken from opencv VideoCapture which seems to suggest that the opencv version does something like rescale the image....I might have to inspect the codebase for VideoCapture to find out...but was wondering if anyone knew.

Comment: Actually I use the frames to do image processing involving 3d to 2d projection and inverse projection based upon a pin-hole camera model. The raspivid version seems to work but the transformation performed with the VideoCapture produces notable error suggesting . However, it is the opencv implementation that I need rather than using raspivid....

Comment: present your methodology. I am reasonably sure that opencv's videocapture **does not** rescale anything. it requests the given size from the device. if you see any differences, show them here, and show how you created those measurements (source code, not text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem the answer is the following:

raspivid -o myvid.h264 -w 640 -h 480 -t 60000

produces a video file of the .h264 format.

Frames of the video are produced by 4x4 binning followed by scale.

As output is 640 x 480 frames, the following is done.

2592/2 = 1296; 1296/2 = 648

1944/2 = 972; 972/2=486

then scale 648 x 486 to 640 x 480 using a scale factor of (640.0/648.0).

I am not sure if this concurs with the raspivid documentation which seems to suggest the contrary e.g. from documentation I was expecting cropping to the correct image size not scaling. However, inspecting video output suggests the that scaling takes place rather than cropping.

Method was to take video as above of camera calibration checkerboard. Extract frames from video and compare size of and position checkerbaord squares with corresponding image taken via cv::VideoCapture.

Image from cv::VideoCapture was formulated as described by Christoph Rackwitz e.g.

do binning as above to get 648 x 486 image then crop to the desired 640 x 480 image size. Cropping appears to take the central 640 x 480 image regione.g. it drops the first 3 rows and the last 3 rows of the 648 x 486 image and drops the first and last 4 columns in each row.